# Cannot tick "Generate Library Layout" Visual Studio UWP

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp

I am getting the error

*Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\UnitTestApp.xbf" because it was not found.*

and

*Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\HovmandUnitTest.xr.xml" because it was not found.*

when trying to build my unit test project, in the same solution as the project being tested.

Searching around on google and here, and apparently you have to tick "Generate library layout" in the build options. I tried, and the checkbox is gray and untickable in both the actual project, and the unit test project.

[image: Like this]

I can't find anyone else with the same issue. Tested on 2 PCs, neither can tick the checkbox.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find anyone else with the same issue. Tested on 2 PCs, neither can tick the checkbox.

You could not use this option within your UWP project. Because, you can't generate UWP project to a library. You could only use it in the class library project.

[image]